Is $\sqrt{2}$ an element of the set $\{k \bmod 2\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$?
I'm exploring the properties of the set formed by taking the modulo $\pi$ of natural numbers, specifically $\{k \bmod 2\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. This set includes all values $k - 2n\pi$ where $0 \leq k - 2n\pi < 2\pi$ for natural $k$ and $n$.
My question is about the presence of $\sqrt{2}$ in this set. While I understand that the set can approximate any number in $[0, 2\pi)$ arbitrarily closely, I'm curious how to prove that there is an exact match or not.
Please feel free to fix my tags and let me know how the field of mathematics that deals with this kind of problems is called.

Are you asking if there are integers $k,n$ such that $\sqrt 2 =k+2\pi ,n$?  Clearly not, since $\pi$ is transcendental and $\sqrt 2 $ isn't an integer.,

What if I replace $\pi$ by non transcendental $\sqrt{3}$. How to approach it?

@hans in that case you wonder whether there is an integer solution to the equation $k-n\sqrt3 = \sqrt2$. Can you figure out the rest?

$\pi$ is a transcendental number, meaning it is not the solution of any non-trivial polynomial with integer coefficients. If we had $\sqrt{2} = k-2n\pi$ then this would imply that $(k-2n\pi)^2-2=0$, thus contradicting that $\pi$ is transcendental.
To answer your further question in the comments, "could we solve $\sqrt{2} = k-2n\sqrt{3}$"? the answer in that case is still no. Generally problems of this nature would be best understood in the context of Galois Theory. It turns out that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ (the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$) has the structure of a (4-dimensional) $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, with basis $\{1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\}$, meaning that the only possible solution to $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}=0$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$ is $a=b=c=d=0$.
If you wanted a more direct elementary proof though, $\sqrt{2} = k-2n\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow 2=(k-2n\sqrt{3})^2=k^2 -4kn\sqrt{3}+12n^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{3}=\frac{k^2+12n^2-2}{4kn} \in \mathbb{Q}$, but since we know that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational this is a contradiction.
